# Macbook pro Battery Question

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery

Is it normal for the maximum mAH to fluctuate by 100's from time to time for a 2012 macbook pro?

Comment: What do you mean by "fluctuate by 100's" This is a little ambiguous.

Comment: well from 5000 it became 4900 max capacity and i always plug in my mac and use the battery few times a wk

Answer (score 3):

I've never been concerned with such a small measurement error. I'd be interested in seeing more data. If you make a month's measurements at least daily - please post and share. Perhaps something is concerning but the small fluctuation you report isn't concerning to me.